# Mongo does not appear in phpinfo after an installation

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, debian

I've followed the following procedure in order to install MongoDB with PHP on Debian 9 :

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

sudo apt-get install dirmngr --install-recommends
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 0x673A03E4C1DB921F
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org mongodb-org-server
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
sudo systemctl start mongodb

sudo apt install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
sudo bash
write extension=mongodb.so dans php.ini (in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini)
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

But Mongo does not appear in phpinfo(), and I get `Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found` on run.

I've already tried to restart.

Comment: did you `write extension=mongodb.so dans php.ini (in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini)
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service` ?

Comment: The end of the procedure ? Yes